# htaccess file on Magento director not working

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, htaccess

I need to remove `index.php` from Magento website url. I have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls. I have followed the same instruction and successfully remove `index.php` from the url on localhost.

But while on server it is not working. url redirect is working properly but it is showing 404 not found error message. I have alse set up `.htaccess` file as given in the instruction but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^helloworld$ /index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In my server all file and folder owner is root. Any kind of suggestion would help.

Comment: If your server runs on nGinx, the `.htaccess` file will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the web server you are using ? Apache or nGinx ?

**Updated Answer**

Since you are using Apache, make sure that you have enabled `mod_rewrite` in your server. To enable `mod_rewrite`, follow the steps in this page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

The above page includes instructions to enable the use of `.htaccess` file also. That needs to be done too.

Do not use your own `.htaccess` file. Instead use the one provided by Magento out-of-the box.

**Updated Answer - 2**

Have you verified that under **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use web server rewrites** is set to **Yes** ?

**Updated Answer - 3**

To remove `index.php` from home page URL, you need to write rules in `.htaccess` file only. This is why I asked you to use the `.htaccess` file provided by Magento. That will do all these things out-of-the-box.

**Updated Answer - 4**

Add this rule to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
redirect 301 /home http://www.yourdomain.com
```

Comment: I am using Apache web server with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @SuvojitMondal I have updated the answer

Comment: mod_rewrite is already enabled and same htaccess is working properly on localhost and my server is using ubuntu 14.04 and not 16.04. I have also tried to create a conf file inside conf-available. Can you please guide me how can write configuration directly to mods-available folder? any way of making url rewriting is fine.

Comment: @SuvojitMondal I have updated the answer

Comment: Now its working properly for all other url but for home page accessible through 3 url base_url, base_url/index.php, and base_url/index.php/. How can I make it so that website will be accessible only through base_url?

Comment: @SuvojitMondal I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I have replaced htaccess with default magento htaccess file. Now also home page available via default_url/index.php. Can you please guide me what I need to change?

Comment: @SuvojitMondal I have updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70214/discussion-between-suvojit-mondal-and-n-karthic-kannan).